# How to fetch filtered data in Javascript from rest-framework

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, fetch-api, django-filter

**I need to filter the generals using their team ID. But I cannot implement it.**

my code:

In choose.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelectorAll('.card-title').forEach(team => {
        let team_id = parseInt(team.dataset.team)
        console.log(team_id)
        fetch(`/generals?team=${team_id}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
            })
        });
    })
```

In views.py:

```
class GeneralView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = General.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GeneralSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ('team',)
```

In urls.py:

```
path('generals', views.GeneralView.as_view(), name='general_view')
```

In my browser console,. `console.log(team_id)` comes correctly but `console.log(result)` does not come correctly.

In one reload

[image: One reload]

In another reload
[image: Another reload]

How to solve the problem?

Comment: looks ok for me, what is the problem? the responses will never be in the same order, it depends on how long the fetch took for each request.

Comment: may change your log to `console.log(team_id, result)`. than you will see which response you get for each team_id